# Is there any way that all templates should inherit mother template

Tags: php, templates, symfony

I am using symfony for my web application.

I have many templates in my folder without any extend tag.

Currently they just open with their own content, but I want that all those should extends from mother template.

I know that use this:

```
{% extends 'AnmeBundle::layout.html.twig' %}
{% block body %}
```

Is there any way to do that without writing that in every tenmplate file?

Comment: No. There is no way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

**For Symfony 2.0**

I believe you can do a workaround by copying

```
TwigBundle/Resources/views/layout.html.twig
```

to

```
app/Resources/TwigBundle/views/layout.html.twig
```

There you can overide the Twig base file and it should affect all your templates.

in the future when starting a project, I would create a base.html.twig template and include that in all other templates when you create them rather than overloading the twig base

I highly recomend RTM: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html

**For Symfony 1.4**

layout.php (in apps//templates/layout.php) is the default global template. The global templates are used for common code (headers, footers, bot codes, google analytics).

You can create you own global templates in the same folder as layout.php and force different actions to use different global templates using the view.yml for that modules.

like so:

```
indexSuccess:
  layout: my_layout
```

or you can do it programmatically in the action:

```
$this->setLayout('my_layout');
```

or in the template

```
<?php decorate_with('my_layout') ?>
```

I highly recomend RTM: http://www.symfony-project.org/gentle-introduction/1_4/en/07-Inside-the-View-Layer